# Add a Right-Click Event to dynamic created Buttons in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dynamic, right-click

```
List<Button> buttonlist = new List<Button>();
for(int i = 0; i< 5;i++){
Button but = new Button();
but.Name = Convert.ToString(i);
but.Location = new Point(50 + i * 20, 50);
but.Size = new Size(20,20);
buttonlist.Add(but);
but.Click += delegate {
//It's a Leftclick 
//Code do stuff
 }
this.Controls.Add(but);
}
```

At the moment I'm making a little Puzzle-Game with C# in Visual Studio 2017.
I create some Buttons dynamicly and when I make a Left-Click on it, it do some stuff. At the moment, nothing happen, when I right-click it.
I don't know how to add a "Right-Click" Event for each Button. The should all do the same if I right-click it.

Have someone a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're using the wrong click event handler. Don't use `MouseClick`, it doesn't allow right-clicks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Anything
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] _)
        {
            var form = new Form();
            List<Button> buttonlist = new List<Button>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Button but = new Button();
                but.Name = Convert.ToString(i);
                but.Location = new Point(50 + i * 20, 50);
                but.Size = new Size(20, 20);
                buttonlist.Add(but);
                but.MouseUp += (s, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                    {
                        // do your thing
                    }
                };
                form.Controls.Add(but);
            }

            form.ShowDialog();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, despite official documentation claiming otherwise, you are correct. The Click event and MouseClick events doesn't even seem to fire when you right click a button. +1.